# in Liferay, an event fire to multiple instances of the same receiving portlet is only received by one instance

Tags: jsf, primefaces, liferay, liferay-6, portlet

I'm developing a liferay application using liferay 6.2.2 with JSF portlets.

I have on my page 2 instances of a portlet A (which fire the event) and 2 instances of a portlet B (which can receive the event).

EDIT : I'm using Liferay Client side IPC system with js for the sending/receiving of the event.

My objective is for portlet B1 to receive the event sent by portlet A1 and the same for the 2 others (B2 from A2).

Managed beans are ViewScoped (ajax compatible). In order to select which portlet should process the correct event, I use portlet ID (the receiverId is in the event payload).

All portlets are instanceable (true) and ajaxable(true).
At the moment, when I sent the event from A1 to B1, everything works fine.
When I try to send from A2 to B2, nothing happens.

The portlet Id sent through the payload of the event matches the intended receiving portlet.

A managed bean instance for each portlet instance is correctly created during the init (@PostConstruct) phase of the page (I have two different addresses for the managed bean instances), when the page is either loaded or reloaded.

The intended behavior when firing an event is for each receiving portlet to check if the portlet Id in the payload matches its own id. If yes, the method called continue. If not, the method is stopped(return;).

The problem is :
 Only one managed bean instance (say B1) is called (2 times) when the event is fired (Liferay.fire / Liferay.on mechanism), while it was expected that each instance of the Managed bean (B1 and B2) should be called one time.

thanks you for your time reading me

Comment: Please mention which type of managed beans is used. Also, look into below link for issue resolution. If you still fails, let me know. [making-distinctions-between-different-kinds-of-jsf-managed-beans](https://www.liferay.com/en_GB/web/neil.griffin/blog/-/blogs/making-distinctions-between-different-kinds-of-jsf-managed-beans)

Comment: I'm confused. First I thought of events as JSR-286 events. Later you mention Liferay.fire and Liferay.on, which are rather client side javascript expressions. Please clarify.

Comment: @NeerajGautam I'm using support managed bean. As far as I can tell as I'm not at work, I don't have any issues with mixed types but I will check it in depth first thing Monday morning and tell you how things goes

Comment: @OlafKock I'm using the liferay IPC system on the client side based on js

Comment: @GaelOnno: I was able to  reproduce your problem with a very simple test project (1 emitter and 2 receiver). Only one instance of the receiver is called, while the number of calls is equal to the total number of receivers (included the receivers you have already removed !!!).To see this, you may add a static counter in the ManagedBean receiver  event  action.

Comment: **Note:** [JSF portlets should not be `ajaxable`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-faces/blob/master/demos/bridge/jsf2-portlet/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/liferay-portlet.xml#L11). Although I doubt that is causing your issue.

Comment: @stiemannkj1 I changed to ajaxable = false and the problem is still there !